# Excel File opened under Ubuntu, read by R, OpenOffice

Tags: excel, r, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a bunch of Excel files which are updated on a daily basis on a Windows machine. I transfer them to a Ubuntu machine and want to open them there. Specifically, I want to read the files as a database under R.

A couple years ago, I used ODBC under a Windows machine to open Excel files through R. Is there any way, I can do this with R under Ubuntu?

I could make a database .ODB file for the corresponding XLS files using OpenOffice, but I don't know of a way to connect to a .ODB database. OpenOffice seems to have ways to connect TO databases, but no way to connect to ODB.

Thanks for any potential solutions.

Comment: append: when I say 'read files as database' I mean, it would be nice to use SQL to fetch data from the worksheets.

Comment: sqldf package could be an option: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to get away with using [xls2csv](http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/) from `apt-get install catdoc` to dump the Excel files to CSV.  Then you can pretty much pick your poison as to how they get proccessed from there. `read.csv.sql` from the `sqldf` package could be very handy if you want to extract information using SQL statements.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: it is possible with a system call (see: ?system) at least.

Comment: given that gdata and xlsx are both failing me with memory issues, I might have to give xls2csv a try soon.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: Catdoc's `xls2csv` utility is a command-line tool which is accessible through a `system` call from R.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) package, which has no special requirements (like [xlsReadWrite](http://www.swissr.org/) and others), so it can be easily used under Linux. Although it only reads (and writes) xlsx format.

Another aprouch could be using `read.xls` function in [gdata](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/index.html) package, which first convers xls files to csv, and read those dataframes. You will need Perl and [xls2csv](http://search.cpan.org/~ken/xls2csv-1.06/script/xls2csv) installed, which is not a big problem under Linux.

Comment: The xlsx package requires that Java be installed.  `read.xls` in gdata requires that perl be installed. `xls2csv` is part of the gdata package and it does not have to be separately installed.  There is a discussion of the various alternatives available, including xlsx and gadata, for reading Excel spreadsheets in the R wiki: http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows

Comment: I tried working with xlsx package, but I seem to run into memory problems with it. The spreadsheets are not humongous, about 100 - 150 Mb, but reading even a sheet to a dataframe fails.

Answer (score 2):

Your ODBC solution should work on Linux, providing you install the `uniXODBC` package (for your OS, you might also need the `unixODBC-devel` package if compiling `RODBC`) and the `RODBC` package for R. The link Gabor provides in his comment to @daroczig's answer has some details of RODBC on linux; note the points about this being read-only on Linux and the potentially difficult set-up.

You might well be better off with the options @daroczig and Gabor suggest, but if you are familiar with ODBC you might want to give it a try on Ubuntu also.

Comment: Gaving, thanks. I was not sure whether the RODBC option would work with Excel files under Linux. From somewhere it was stuck in my head that RODBC + Excel needs some Excel specific drivers, which are not available on Linux. Actually, I still don't know how to make an Excel file accessible via ODBC on Linux. I have done that on Windows. And I am ok with ODBC on Linux as such, I use some other DB with R via unixODBC . .

Comment: Gavin, do you have any idea of how to make .XLSX files available via unixODBC?

Comment: @Vishal Belsare - no, sorry, I don't. I find ODBC a bit of a black art on Linux. I only provided my answer in case you already were comfortable with setting up ODBC resources on Linux. I hate Excel with a passion - I insist anyone working with me exports csv or similar files if they want me to do analysis on them.

Comment: Not a problem. I am fine using unixODBC, but there seems to be no way of pipelining to a XLSX file on Linux this way. ODBC works fine with any other, like Postgres or MySQL. I share your sentiment for Excel - but the financial industry at large is addicted to it, and I am dealing with data taken from a financial data terminal (Bloomberg/Reuters) in the form of XLSX files. I just need to read those regularly, and then I populate a RDBMS to carry out my work . .. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

There's another solution - host your data in a database to which both your machines have access. Postgres or MySQL will cost you nothing or MS-SQL server if you've got cash rattling around. What you seem to be trying to do is exactly what networked RDBMSs were designed for. You'll be able to play with the data in Excel and R on remote machines. Win.

Copying Excel files around is a massive fail waiting to happen. Get yourself a real RDBMS. I'd go for Postgres.

Comment: I am constrained by the data necessarily living in Excel files. (think files updated on a financial data terminal). I would do away with Excel totally, if it were not the data conduit. btw. I use Postgres+R, MonetDB+R for other projects . . In this case, I need to be able to read from Excel files which are updated daily, and then I intend to populate a RDBMS, most likely Postgres